# iPhone Rotation of UINavigationController view as Subview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm having a problem getting a UINavigationController to lay its table out properly after autorotation, when the UITableview is a subview.

What happens, is that the navigation bar gets shifted down about 20px, and the table becomes either too short and too wide in landscape, or too narrow in portrait.

Anyone have any suggestions? This has been driving me nuts for the past month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a known issue with the iPhone 3.0 beta. Since it's under NDA, it can't be discussed openly here. However, there is a [discussion](https://devforums.apple.com/message/69293) on the Apple discussion forums that pertains to this problem. You'll need to be a part of the for-pay iPhone developer program to have access to that thread, as it is in the 3.0 section.

Comment: I'm actually still using 2.2.1 still :)  But I found a way around the problem by just not using UINavigationController for a subview.  I realized after reading a few other related questions here that I can bring it onto the screen with the main view controller's presentModalViewController method, and that seems to be a better approach in my case.  Still, hanks for the quick response.